# Sequelize: Or-condition over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to add an or condition over multiple tables with sequelizejs.
My problem is that I don't know how to use the or operators ($or and Sequelize.or) over more than one table.

Let's say I want to implement the following sql-query:

```
select * from A as a, B as b, C as c where (A.b_id = b.id and b.x = 7) or (A.c_id = C.id and c.z = "test")
```

I would implement only the first condition with sequelize like this:

```
A.findAll({
   include: [{ model: B, where: { x: 7 } }]
})
```

And only the second condition like this:

```
A.findAll({
   include: [{ model: C, where: { z: "test" } }]
})
```

But how do I combine both queries into the one I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
A.findAll({
   include: [{model: B},{model: C}], 
   where: {
     '$or':{
        '$b.x$': 7, 
        '$c.z$': "test"
     }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for accepted answer and glad to hear, up vote if you like answer

Comment: @SaravananNandhan :)

Comment: This doesn't work, as adding multiple tables causes an issue with SQL query. I am not sure of the exact reason other than how the joins function changes when there is more than 1 include. I have tried this with more than 1 table and have receive the error that the table name is missing in the clause