# Query a Sequelize Table by Day of Week in 1 Column and Boolean in another column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query a PostgreSQL database (using Sequelize on node). I need to pull out data in the table that matches the current dow (day of week) and also another boolean column in another table. The idea is that I want to pull out data that have a certain boolean to be true, that fall on a Friday (for example).

Currently, this is the code that I have.

```
        const dayFilter = sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('date_part', 'dow', sequelize.col('start_date')))
        const campaign = await Campaign.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    dayFilter,
                     { isLive: true, }
                ]
            }
        })
```

I'm trying to use the date_part function from [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) docs.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062925/sequelize-or-condition-over-multiple-tables

Comment: Hmm, I think my main issue now is that I don't know how to write my sequelize query to query by day of week, and I haven't been able to find anything on it!

Comment: Add the related model definitions to your question. So we can help.

Comment: hello, i managed to fix it. 

To elaborate, I have a campaigns table, with columns is_live and start_date, and I wanted to pull data where is_live = true and start_date = new Date().getDay().

This solved it for me: 
        const dow = new Date().getDay()
        const campaign = await Campaign.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('EXTRACT(DOW FROM campaigns.start_date)'), dow),
                    { 
                        isLive: true, 
                    }
                ]
            }
        })

Comment: You can write the solution as an answer. Explain what was the problem, what is the solution with the answer. Then accept your own answer. So others with the same problem will have a nice explained solution :)