# Sequelize: OR query across 2 or more table relations

Tags: sequelize.js

I was looking at this StackOverflow solution:

[Sequelize: Or-condition over multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062925/sequelize-or-condition-over-multiple-tables)

I tried to replicate the solution but I get an error if I have more than 1 model included.

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "files"
```

Tables:

- documents
- files
- users

Table Relations:

- documents.belongsTo(models.files)
- documents.belongsto(modes.users)

Query on documents:

```
where = {
    [Op.or]: [
      {
        '$files.name$': {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${$search.like}%`,
        },
    },
    {
        documentName: {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${$search.like}%`,
        },
    },
    {
        '$users.name$': {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${$search.like}%`,
        },
    },
   ],
  };
```

Can anyone assist/provide suggestions on how to do an OR query across 2 or more table relations?

Comment: Did you try to set `subQuery: false` option?

Comment: @Anatoly Please explain, not sure what subQuery is suppose to do

Comment: `subQuery: false` means to use JOIN/LEFT JOIN tables themselves instead of join subqueries constructed from these tables.

Comment: Thanks for that, would not have found that solution by myself. Let me know if you want to post the solution here so I can accept it?

Comment: ok, posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `subQuery: false` option to your sequelize query like this:

```
const where = // here is a where condition
const documents = await db.documents.findAll({
  subQuery: false,
  where
})
```

subQuery: false means to use JOIN/LEFT JOIN tables themselves instead of join subqueries constructed from these tables

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @Anatoly's answer in the comments, the way to resolve this is by adding subQuery: false, i.e

```
context.params.sequelize = {
    raw: false,
    subQuery: false,
    include: [
        {
            model: files,
        },
        {
            model: users,
        },
    ],
};
```

"subQuery: false means to use JOIN/LEFT JOIN tables themselves instead of join subqueries constructed from these tables"